# Django Search functionality: form returns None

Tags: django

i am trying to build a django search functionality for my app but the input form keeps returning  a none

views.py

```py
def search(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      query = request.POST.get('text')
      houses = Product.objects.filter(name__contains='query')
      context = {
         'houses':houses,
      }
   return render (request, 'searchresult.html', context)
```

search.html

```html
<form>
   <input type='text' placeholder='search houses>
   <button type='submit'>Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, your python indentation is invalid, and your HTML is also invalid on the `input` line. I will assume this is a typo in the question, but if not, you have issues there.

Your main problem is the filter for houses:

```
houses = Product.objects.filter(name__contains='query')
```

is looking for a name containing the string "query". You need the variable you've just defined.

```
houses = Product.objects.filter(name__contains=query)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have an indentation issue in the code you have posted.
2. You need to add `action` and `method` in your Form.

   ```
    <form action="/url_of_search/" method="post">
   ```
3. Missing quote in `input` line.

   ```
    <input type='text' placeholder='search houses'>
   ```
4. You need to use `query` instead of `'query'` in the filter.

   ```
   Product.objects.filter(name__contains=query)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Things missing in html code:

1. form action attribute
2. form method attribute
3. input field name attribute

```html
<!-- add form attributes method and action -->
<form method="POST" action="{% url '<url_name>' %}">
   <!-- add input attribute name to identify the field and pass the value in request body -->
   <input type='text' placeholder='search houses' name='search_text'>
   <button type='submit'>Search</button>
</form>
```

update views for search

```py
def search(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      # use input field name to get the search text
      query = request.POST.get('search_text')
      houses = Product.objects.filter(name__contains=query)
      context = {
         'houses':houses,
      }
   return render (request, 'searchresult.html', context)
```